# How to improve the UX of self driving cars?

Tags: design, user-expectation

**What are the most important things a self driving can do to be trusted by humans?**

---

Google claims that a driverless car doesn't have to be perfect -- it only needs to be better than humans. Is this really the case?  In spite of the fact that [Google's driverless cars](http://www.cnn.com/2014/04/28/tech/innovation/google-self-driving-car/) have logged over 700,000 miles both accident and ticket free -- [one study found](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~alaink/SmartDrivingCars/PDFs/SeapineDriverlessCarHarrisPollFinal.pdf) that 88% of people would be worried about riding in a self driving car listing the following reasons:

- More than half (59 percent) are worried about liability issues, such as who would be responsible if a driverless car is involved in an accident.
- 52 percent fear a hacker could breach the driverless car's system and gain
  control of the vehicle.
- More than one-third (37 percent) worry auto companies, insurers, advertisers
  and municipalities may collect personal data such as where the car goes and how
  fast it's traveling.
- Only 12 percent said they would not be worried about riding in a driverless car.

Comment: Although the topic is interesting, this is an incredibly broad question. We are a Question and Answer site, not a UX discussion one. Is there a way you can narrow this down to a specific area that you need a solution to? As the help centre states: ["Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: oh man I'm 0 for 2 on asking questions that are too broad.  :(  I was just generally curious on ways to earn a users trust.  At some point the current car had to win over the trusty horse so maybe it is just a matter of time.

Comment: There is certainly an interesting question in here, but as currently written it's just too much for the format of this site I'm afraid.